# Rich Text Editor Cell Properties

Tags: richtext-editor

Folks,

got some strange behaviour withe RTE in sitecore, when you create a table, then edit one of the cells, it renders back what looks like a copy of the original table inside the selected cell, see below

[image]

when you click "Accept" the extra table disappears, but leaves a ton of :nbsp tags, any thoughts?

thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To resolve the issue, please update the Telerik RTE assemblies to the newer version:

1. Extract the Telerik.Web.UI.dll and Telerik.Web.UI.Skins.dll assemblies from the attached archives into your \bin folder (replacing the existing ones).
2. Replace the Telerik.Web.UI.XML file in your \bin folder with the attached one.
3. Add the Telerik.Web.UI assembly binding to your web.config:

   ```
   <runtime>
     <assemblyBinding xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1">
   ...
    <dependentAssembly>
   <assemblyIdentity name="Telerik.Web.UI" publicKeyToken="121fae78165ba3d4" />
   <bindingRedirect oldVersion="2015.1.401.45" newVersion="2015.3.930.45" />
    </dependentAssembly>
   </assemblyBinding>
   </runtime>
   ```

   Files you can find at this [link](https://www.dropbox.com/sh/wvj4302q23v2ums/AADFzt-4_8qrJHVHRxzrXXaIa?dl=0)